# How do I keep the sand out of my eyes?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

The Damp Oasis level is full of sand and I can't see or do anything.

How do I get the sand out of my eyes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your stickerized Vacuum Thing to suck it up all up.

To get the Vacuum, go to Surfshine Harbor, and head to right to find a building with a door pasted on sideways. Go into Paperize mode, peel it off, and then put it back on upright.

Next, head through the building and then out the door in the back. Walk over to the next door and you'll be able to make your way up to the second floor. On this floor you will find the Vacuum Thing and a HP-Up Heart.

Comment: Where do I find the vacuum?

Comment: Go to Surfshine Harbor, and head to right to find a building with a door pasted on sideways. Go into Paperize mode, peel it off, and then put it back on upright. Next, head through the building and then out the door in the back. Walk over to the next door and you'll be able to make your way up to the second floor. On this floor you will find the Vacuum Thing and a HP-Up Heart.

Comment: While you're in Damp Oasis and the sand is still there, Kersti will offer a helpful comment suggesting that you visit Surfshine Harbor if you ask her for advice.  I think several of the game's puzzles have hints like this, that direct you to where you can find an appropriate "thing" sticker.